# the field uploadFile exceeds

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying send Excel from client with SpringBoot but I  get error when I get File. I add in my propertys 10MB or 300MB for maximum but It doesn't run.

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException:
>   The field uploadFile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576
>   bytes.
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl$1.raiseError(FileUploadBase.java:630)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.checkLimit(LimitedInputStream.java:76)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:135)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2869)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3216)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]

My pom.xml

In my pom.xml I have version 1 and 1.15.10 realease

```
   <groupId>tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>tutorial</name>
    <description>Demo project for tutorial CRUD</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I added in application.properties ... nothing.

```
maxFileSize: 300Mb
maxRequestSize: 300Mb
```

EDIT: 
however I can download this File from SpringBoot. But I can't send this File for read content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to set different properties to increase the upload size:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1Mb
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

By the way: the prefix has changed for Spring Boot 2. It is `spring.servlet` there. But since you are using 1.5, those above should work for you.

There is also an excellent tutorial for Spring Boot 2: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/